# Как сделать сокет (pipe) неблокируемым в одном и блокируемым в другом процессе?

Tags: c, linux

Есть файловый дескиптор сокета (socketpair или pipe - без разницы). Требуется, чтобы он в одном процессе блокировался на `read()`, а в другом нет (т.е. при отсутствии данных `read()` возвращает -1 и `errno == EAGAIN`).

Дело в том, что

```
int newfd = dup(oldfd);
fcntl (newfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(newfd,F_GETFL)|O_NONBLOCK);
```

Делает неблокируемым **оба дескриптора**. Вызов `fcntl()` до `fork()` или после ситуацию не меняет.

Аналогичное поведение и для tty и для обычного файла. С ними проще (можно независимо переоткрыть, например, /dev/tty), но меня интересует именно сокет (или pipe).

Какие есть идеи?

Если считаете, что это в принципе невозможно, тоже откликайтесь.

Возможно следующая информация окажется полезной:

> Each  open  file  description has certain associated status flags, ini‐
>    tialized by open(2) and possibly modified by fcntl().  Duplicated  file
>    descriptors  (made with dup(2), fcntl(F_DUPFD), fork(2), etc.) refer to
>    the same open file description, and thus share  the  same  file  status
>    flags.

IMHO из этого следует, что мне нужно каким-то образом (*вот в этом и суть вопроса*)
получить дескриптор на новую запись в таблице файлов, ссылающуюся на те же очереди данных, что и заданный сокет.

P.S.

Нисколько не сомневался, но проверил. `execl() (system())` не влияет.

Comment: видела подобное использование дескрипторов только с файлами, там это прокатывает, так как один и тот же файл можно открыть несколько раз и получить несколько дескрипторов, но как сделать то же самое с сокетом представляется плохо ввиду отсутствия у него имени. Могу предложить попробовать сделать то же самое, только с вызовом dup2() в дочернем процессе, тогда по идее должно быть 2 разных дескриптора...

Comment: Может его просто перенаправить в named pipe и уже от него плясать?

Comment: @margosh, dup() и dup2() в этом плане работают одинаково (dup3 тоже не подойдет). 

Вообще, разница между fd=dup(old) и fd=dup2(old,new) в том, что dup2() закроет new (если он был открыт) и вернет копию old (т.е. fd), численно равную new, а dup() возвращает копию old, ничего не закрывая.

Дескрипоры, конечно разные, но новый дескриптор будет ссылаться на ту же запись таблицы файлов системы (*не процесса !*), что и старый и разделять одни и те же file  status flags (естественно **кроме** флага **FD_CLOEXEC**, который находится в таблице дескрипторов процесса) .

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, если честно, то не понимаю как это сделать. 

Вы предлагаете соединить дескриптор сокета с открытым дескриптором FIFO, потом открыть еще раз FIFO и сделать этот дескриптор неблокируемым ?

Вот как соединить сокет с FIFO объясните поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: @avp, если так, то нет смысла использовать ни одну из этих функций. Ситуацию, которой Вы хотите добиться, дал бы повторный вызов open() для одного файла, но с сокетом это видимо не пройдет. Скажите, а зачем Вам необходимо реализовать именно такое поведение?

Comment: @margosh, можно сказать просто - научный интерес. 

Вообще, была идея использовать это в моделировании поведения одной многопроцессной системки. Если быстренько не решится, придумаем что-нибудь другое.

Comment: @avp, можете не обращать внимания на мой бред, поскольку я не знаю C :) Предположил это исключительно на уровне алгоритма.

> Вот как соединить сокет с FIFO объясните поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Читать из сокета и писать в FIFO. Из FIFO только читать.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, идея читать в каком-то потоке и перебрасывать прочитанное понятна. Но, меня в данном случае, интересует другой подход.

Answer (score 1):

Из приведенной цитаты следует, что у каждого открытого файла будет только свой дескриптор (и похоже один). И модифицируя с одного места, изменяем и в другом.

По сути вопроса - а почему не использовать блокирующий режим и вызывать recv с параметром MSG_DONTWAIT ?

Comment: @KoVadim, хорошая идея. Просто поменять read на recv. 

"Научный интерес", конечно остался. А для практики идея, то что надо.

Comment: а если заглянуть внутрь документации по recv, то там такое можно найти... У меня в свое время один флаг в recv убрал кучу кода.
Суть - по первому пришедшему байту нужно было определить, каким протоколом пришел клиент (текстовым, xml или ssl). Первый байт однозначно идентифицировал протокол. Вначале было построена своя система буферизации и передачи массива внутрь библиотек. Теперь - просто считывание 1 байта без удаления его с очереди, анализ, создание нужного обработчика, который получает дескриптор сокета.

Comment: MSG_PEEK известная вещь. 

Вообще-то, в данном случае, я скорее заинтересован в некотором роде защите одних процессов, от изменения O_NONBLOCK в других для разделяемого сокета.